# From MySQL 5 table, Increment counter and limit same occurrences

Tags: mysql, counter, limit

I have a MySQL 5 table as shown below

| id | emp_id | name | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D01 | Bob | Director |
| 2 | S01 | Jason | Staff |
| 3 | S02 | Mark | Staff |
| 4 | D02 | David | Director |
| 5 | S03 | Rob | Staff |
| 6 | D04 | Will | Director |
| 7 | S04 | James | Staff |
| 8 | S05 | Phil | Staff |

Per page, I want to display 2 Directors with Staffs under them. Therfore the pages should look like

```
First page
```

| id | emp_id | name | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D01 | Bob | Director |
| 2 | S01 | Jason | Staff |
| 3 | S02 | Mark | Staff |
| 4 | D02 | David | Director |
| 5 | S03 | Rob | Staff |

```
Second page
```

| id | emp_id | name | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | D04 | Will | Director |
| 7 | S04 | James | Staff |
| 8 | S05 | Phil | Staff |

Is this possible with MySQL Queries or do I have to write separate function to maintain a counter for Directors? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the relationships between directors and their staff stored?  Your current table does not seem to have this information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Director-Staff relation is defined by the position while sorting by `id`:

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT id, emp_id, name, position,
                SUM(position = 'Director') OVER (ORDER BY id) + 1 grp 
         FROM test )
SELECT id, emp_id, name, position
FROM cte
WHERE grp DIV 2 = @page_number
ORDER BY id;
```

> I have edited my question and included the MySQL version to 5. – Jay

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.emp_id, t1.name, t1.position
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
WHERE t2.position = 'Director'
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.emp_id, t1.name, t1.position
HAVING (COUNT(*) + 1) DIV 2 = @page_number
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a5b8aec57b01a617e07f3051d149164e

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the WITH clause. because WITH clause is not supported for MySQL prior to MySQL 8.0

Comment: @Jay You should specify precise MySQL version on the top of you question!

Comment: I have edited my question and included the MySQL version to 5.

Comment: @Jay Look up the meaning of the word "precise"in the explanatory dictionary. Answer updated.